# [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of async component loader at <AsyncComponentWrapper> at <App> when loading a SFC using vue3-sfc-loader

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-router

Here is the code:

```
<div id="app">
    <h1>Hello App!</h1>
    <helloworld></helloworld>
    <p>
        <router-link to="/">Go to Home</router-link>
        <router-link to="/about">Go to About</router-link>
        <router-link to="/about/1234">Go to About/1234</router-link>
    </p>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>

<script>
    const { loadModule } = window['vue3-sfc-loader'];

    const Home = {
        template: '<div>Home</div>'
    };

    const About = {
        template: '<div>About</div>',
        created() {
            console.debug("About created");
            this.$watch(
                () => this.$route.params,
                (toParams, previousParams) => {
                    // react to route changes...
                    console.debug(toParams, previousParams);
                }
            )
        }
    }

    const routes = [
        { path: '/', component: Home },
        { path: '/about', component: About },
        { path: '/about/:userId', component: About }
    ];

    const options = {
        moduleCache: {
            vue: Vue,
        },
        getFile(filepath) {
            fetch(filepath).then(res => {
                if ( !res.ok )
                    throw Object.assign(new Error(res.statusText + ' ' + filepath), { res });
                return {
                    getContentData: asBinary => asBinary ? res.arrayBuffer() : res.text(),
                }
            });
        },
        addStyle(textContent) {
            console.debug(textContent);
            const style = Object.assign(document.createElement('style'), { textContent });
            const ref = document.head.getElementsByTagName('style')[0] || null;
            document.head.insertBefore(style, ref);
        },
    }

    const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
        history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
        routes, // short for `routes: routes`
    });

    const app = Vue.createApp({
        router: router,
        components: {
            'helloworld': Vue.defineAsyncComponent(() => loadModule('/real-estate/vues/helloworld.vue', options)),
        },
        data(){
            return {
            }
        },
        async mounted(){
        },
        methods: {
        },
        filters: {
        }
    }).use(router).mount('#app');

</script>
```

All of this is example code for Vue Router and vue3-sfc-loader except for the third . The helloworld component is right out of the Vue docs.

I do not use node so I need the vue3-sfc-loader. I have been using httpvueloader on Vue 2 for years with excellent results.

I have read the vue3-sfc-loader docs as well as the article at https://medium.com/@marcel.leusch/use-vue-3-single-file-components-without-compilation-ac2ccb5f15c2 and they agree on the approach.

I commented out the router related code and go the same warning. The vue file is being loaded and the Promise is returning the contents of helloworld.vue.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by replacing the getFile function with another example from the vue3-sfc-loader docs:

```
async getFile(url) {
        const res = await fetch(url);

        if ( !res.ok ) {
            throw Object.assign(new Error(res.statusText + ' ' + url), { res });
        }

        return {
            getContentData: (asBinary) => asBinary ? res.arrayBuffer() : res.text(),
        }
    },
```